# RSA keys...(bob_pub, bob_priv)

Tags: python, python-2.6

i created keys with python rsa lib
this what i did

```
import rsa

(bob_pub, bob_priv) = rsa.newkeys(512)
message = 'hello Bob!'
crypto = rsa.encrypt(message, bob_pub)


message = rsa.decrypt(crypto, bob_priv)
print message
```

this code works fie form me but the problem is how can i save these files on pc so i can save them on usb and i can use them in another place
because for now when i close the python session these files are deleted ... and i want to open these file in another pc so please how can i save the bob_pub, bob_priv, crypto on usb?? or in a file

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`save_pkcs1`](http://stuvel.eu/files/python-rsa-doc/reference.html#rsa.PublicKey.save_pkcs1) method on the keys to store them, then use [`load_pkcs1`](http://stuvel.eu/files/python-rsa-doc/reference.html#rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1) to load them back in.

Comment: when i sore them where it dtores them and when i load them where to load them ??? can i save them to a file in /tmp/ ??

Comment: @user1252274: where files go depends on which pathname you give them, obviously.

Comment: please can u write me an example how to save them on /tmp folder and where to put the pathname

Comment: I don't have the library installed, so I cannot check whether my example would work.

Answer (score -1):

You can store them with pickle.

```
import rsa
import cPickle as p

(bob_pub, bob_priv) = rsa.newkeys(512)
message = 'hello Bob!'
crypto = rsa.encrypt(message, bob_pub)

for var in (bob_pub, bob_priv, crypro):
    p.dump(var,'path/to/file')

message = rsa.decrypt(crypto, bob_priv)
print message
```

you can then load them with `bob_pub=p.load('path/to/bob_pup-file')`